# Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 15, Study Drill #6

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in learning how to code and I have a problem on Exercise 15, Study Drill # 6, written by Zed A Shaw ([link](http://www.souravsengupta.com/int2pro2014/python/LPTHW.pdf) to PDF). It states:

> Start python to start the python shell, and use open from the prompt just like in this program. Notice how you can open files and run read on them from within python?

My issue is when I open python in Powershell (Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec 5 2015 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]), I can't get any files open that I have saved in NotePad++. I can run simple code in Powershell with Python. And the exercise code runs fine when I run it through `C:\User\MyName\lpthw> python ex15.py samplefile.txt`. Yet, when I start python in Powershell and execute

```
filename = "samplefile.txt"
txt = open(filename)
```

I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'samplefile.txt'.

Is my path from NotePad++ wrong? The path I have set up in NotePad++ is

```
*$(FULL_CONTENET_PATH)-C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\$(FULL_CONTENT_PATH) (2.7.11)*
```

Comment: Just provide the full path to the file: `filename = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\..."` Notice that you need to double the backslashes.

Comment: Do you think you could add some formatting to your post, and clean up the typos? It's ever so slightly unreadable.

Comment: I added a link to a PDF, but it seems to be a different version of the book than the one you're using because the study drill in the pdf is #7.

Comment: @Reti43: The study drill is #6 when you take it from the website: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex15.html

Comment: @zondo Cool, didn't think of that. I just clicked on the first link that came up on Google.

Comment: @zondo Thank you very much. It worked just fine. Thank all of you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Install Cygwin and Python Interpreter.

Comment: @ Sandeep thank you for the information but I'm not sure I'd be using Cygwin yet. I will research it and archive this dialogue for future reference though. Thank you for your help.